# Collect node.js servers to client website

Tags: node.js, arduino

I am starting a home project with arduino that will monitor 3 different places and one arduino that will handle my sprinkler system.

I can get information from one arduino to node.js (server 1), but I want to collect information from node.js (servers 1, 2, 3) in one realtime website. 
In the real-time website I only want linkbuttons (server1, server2, etc) that changes color, eg. green for online, gray for offline, and red for trigger alert.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use socket.io in node.js which has a client for the web.

Basically socket.io works with websockets (or similar techs, depending on what your browser supports). So with the client (browser) you connect to your server and listen to some events. When your server has new infos you just emit those to the client. `io.emit('room1', 'online')` and in the browser, when you get that event you can change the color accordingly.
It's pretty straight forward to implement. And there are thousands of examples.